# Is there a way to label each wedge of pie chart in this grid?

Tags: matplotlib, label, pie-chart

I want to have multiple pie charts in a grid.

Each pie chart will have a different number of wedges, values, and labels.

The code below shows multiple labels in one pie chart.

Is there a way to label each wedge of pie-charts in this grid?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def heatmap_with_circles(data_array,row_labels,column_labels,ax=None, cmap=None, norm=None, cbar_kw={}, cbarlabel="", **kwargs):

    for row_index, row in enumerate(row_labels,0):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(column_labels,0):
            print('row_index: %d column_index: %d' %(row_index,column_index))
            if row_index==0 and column_index==0:
                colors=['indianred','orange','gray']
                values=[10,20,30]
            else:
                values=[45,20,38]
                colors=['pink','violet','green']

            wedges, text = plt.pie(values,labels=['0', '2', '3'],labeldistance = 0.25,colors=colors)
            print('len(wedges):%d wedges: %s, text: %s' %(len(wedges), wedges, text))
            radius = 0.45
            [w.set_center((column_index,row_index)) for w in wedges]
            [w.set_radius(radius) for w in wedges]

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[1]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[0]))

    fontsize=10
    ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, fontsize=fontsize)

    #X axis labels at top
    ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False,labeltop=True, labelbottom=False,pad=5)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=55, ha="left", rotation_mode="anchor")

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[1]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[0]+1)-.5, minor=True)

    ax.grid(which="minor", color="black", linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
    ax.tick_params(which="minor", bottom=False, left=False)

data_array=np.random.rand(3,4)
row_labels=['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3']
column_labels=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3','Column4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1.9*len(column_labels),1.2*len(row_labels)))
ax.set_aspect(1.0)
ax.set_facecolor('white')
heatmap_with_circles(data_array,row_labels,column_labels, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

After updating **heatmap_with_circles**

```
def heatmap_with_circles(data_array,row_labels,column_labels,ax=None, cmap=None, norm=None, cbar_kw={}, cbarlabel="", **kwargs):
    labels = ['x', 'y', 'z']

    for row_index, row in enumerate(row_labels,0):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(column_labels,0):
            print('row_index: %d column_index: %d' %(row_index,column_index))
            if row_index==0 and column_index==0:
                colors=['indianred','orange','gray']
                values=[10,20,30]
            else:
                values=[45,20,38]
                colors=['pink','violet','green']

            # wedges, texts = plt.pie(values,labels=['0', '2', '3'],labeldistance = 0.45,colors=colors)
            wedges, texts = plt.pie(values,labeldistance = 0.25,colors=colors)
            print('text:%s len(wedges):%d wedges: %s' %(texts, len(wedges), wedges))
            radius = 0.45
            [w.set_center((column_index,row_index)) for w in wedges]
            [w.set_radius(radius) for w in wedges]
            [text.set_position((text.get_position()[0]+column_index,text.get_position()[1]+row_index)) for text in texts]
            [text.set_text(labels[text_index]) for text_index, text in enumerate(texts,0)]
```

[image]

I got the following image :)

Comment: How do you do that? Also, my code has to write labels for each pie chart but somehow only they are written on the first pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the texts of each pie, get its xy position, add column_index and row_index, and set that as new position.

Some small changes to the existing code:

- `ax.grid(which="minor", ..., clip_on=False)` to make sure the thick lines are shown completely, also near the border
- `ax.set_xlim(xmin=-0.5)` to set the limits

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def heatmap_with_circles(data_array, row_labels, column_labels, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    for row_index, row in enumerate(row_labels, 0):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(column_labels, 0):
            colors = np.random.choice(['indianred', 'orange', 'gray', 'pink', 'violet', 'green'], 3, replace=False)
            values = np.random.randint(10, 41, 3)
            wedges, text = plt.pie(values, labels=['1', '2', '3'], labeldistance=0.25, colors=colors)
            radius = 0.45
            for w in wedges:
                w.set_center((column_index, row_index))
                w.set_radius(radius)
                w.set_edgecolor('white')
                # w.set_linewidth(1)
            for t in text:
                x, y = t.get_position()
                t.set_position((x + column_index, y + row_index))

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[1]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[0]))

    fontsize = 10
    ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, fontsize=fontsize)

    # X axis labels at top
    ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False, labeltop=True, labelbottom=False, pad=5)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=55, ha="left", rotation_mode="anchor")

    # We want to show all minor ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[1] + 1) - .5, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[0] + 1) - .5, minor=True)
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=-.5)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=-.5)

    ax.grid(which="minor", color="black", linestyle='-', linewidth=2, clip_on=False)
    ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", length=0) # hide tick marks

data_array = np.random.rand(3, 4)
row_labels = ['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3']
column_labels = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1.9 * len(column_labels), 1.2 * len(row_labels)))
ax.set_aspect(1.0)
ax.set_facecolor('white')
heatmap_with_circles(data_array, row_labels, column_labels, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pie chart grid with labels]

Comment: Looks way better than mine. Perfect :)

Comment: You could add `ax.tick_params(axis="both", length=0)` to hide the tick marks

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it looks perfect.

Comment: By the way, what creates this white lines between parts of a pie chart? In my case there is no such white lines.

Comment: You can change the edge color of the wedges: `w.set_edgecolor('white')`